# Django Running Python Function to Update Page w/o Refresh

Tags: python, django

I am making a website that tracks population statistics. The site needs to update about every 5 seconds with the latest information.

Here is the relevant code for displaying the pandas df on the page (in a file titled "home.html"):

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>Population Tracker</h1>
        {% for index, label,data in pop_df.itertuples %}
            <div class = "row__data">
                <p>{{label}}: {{data}}</p>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Here is the code for my scraper (in a separate file called "scraper.py")

```
class Scraper():

    def __init__(self):
        self.URL = "https://countrymeters.info/en/Japan"

    def scrape(self):
        "Scrapes the population data once"
        page = requests.get(self.URL)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

        data_div = soup.find_all('div',class_="data_div")[0]
        table = data_div.findAll("table")[0]

        tr = table.findAll('tr')

        labels = []
        numbers = []

        for n, i in enumerate(tr):
            number = i.findAll('td',{"class":"counter"})[0].text # numbers
            label = i.findAll('td',{"class":"data_name"})[0].text # labels

            labels.append(label)
            numbers.append(number)

        pop_df = pd.DataFrame(
            {
                'Labels':labels,
                'Data': numbers
            }
        )
        return pop_df
```

In my views.py file, here is what I have done:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from bsoup_tracker.scraper import Scraper

scraper = Scraper()
df = scraper.scrape()

def home(request):
    context = {
        'pop_df':df
    }
    return render(request,'tracker/home.html',context)
```

Basically, I would like to be able to call the render onto my home.html page every 5 seconds to reupdate the page, without needing refreshes. I have tried to look elsewhere and see that Ajax could help; however I do not know where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Django to render the page, create API and call every after 5 minutes and after getting the results, refresh the HTML content using JavaScript.

If you need more information please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Where could I begin to learn about how to do this?

Comment: The best option is to use Django Rest Framework (DRF) in your project and create APIs. (Check How to install DRF https://www.django-rest-framework.org/  , How to create APIs https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/)

Comment: It's up to you to decide to use API or WebSockets. I'll recommend using WebSocket because the execution required web scraping. This may take some time to execute and it will hold other requests until it returns the response.

Answer (score 1):

`AJAX` stands for "asynchronous JavaScript and XML" so as you thought that would be the way to go if you need to fetch data from your backend and refresh the interface.

The base component to do so in the `XmlHttpRequest` object in vanilla JavaScript. However, I strongly advice using a library like jQuery, to me it's really easier to use. With vanilla JS, jQuery or any other library you choose, you can modify DOM to expose data you got from your backend. The major drawback is that you will probably end up with not so clean code which will get harder and harder to maintain.

Nowadays the most common solution would be to use `djangorestframework` (not mandatory, you can also use django's `JsonResponse`) to create an API along with a nodeJS framework like React or VueJS to create your interface using API's data. That way you will have a lot more control on your interface.

Finally, if you need to have some sort of live website (pulling data and refreshing interface every 5 seconds seems like a poor design pattern to me), you should use websockets for your frontend and ASGI in backend (instead of WSGI). Django-channel is a nice package to do so, but just Google "django websockets" and you will find a lot of documentation.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that. This is just for a project to learn some django / website stuff - I do not intend to actually host it

Comment: Learning websockets  and ASGI is a bit harder that django +ajax but it's very useful. You could have a look at a basic chat tutorial for example.